# cat function not printing the last line of the input file

Tags: c, macos, unix, operating-system, xv6

```
#include <unistd.h> // for close, fork
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // for open

int main()
{
    char *argv[2];
    argv[0] = "cat";
    argv[1] = 0;
    if (fork() == 0)
    {
        close(0);
        open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);
        execvp("cat", argv);
    }
}
```

`input.txt` is:

```
Hello
I
am
Sam
```

But, when I run this code, the output is

```
Hello
I
am
```

Thus, not printing the last line of `input.txt`

Can someone explain the reason for this I am quite new to OS.

Comment: Cannot reproduce; in my case all lines are printed. I am running it on Mac OS.

Comment: @MMZK1526 I was running this on VS code and I encountered this issue, then I ran it directly from the terminal and I got the desired output, is this some issue with VS Code?

Comment: Could be, that would be harder to debug. Do you know what commands are used when you ran it via vsc? Also I don't think that's the issue, but is there anything about newline (\n vs \r\n)?

Comment: gcc cat.c -o cat was used when running in VSCode, and even when I used clang here in the VSCode Terminal, I encountered the same issue. Could you mention what you mean by your second question?

Comment: So on Windows, a newline is encoded with "\r\n", while on UNIX it's just "\n". But I don't think that's causing the problem here. Are you sure the "terminal" in vsc is not hiding something? Can you try to pipe the output to another file and check it manually?

Comment: @MMZK1526 I am using MacOS

Comment: Does your file end with a newline?

Comment: And if you're doing this on a Mac, why is this tagged linux and xv6?

Comment: @Shawn Nope. My mistake, the code which I have written here is from xv6 book. So, I mentioned that. As for linux, it was a mistake, I should have tagged UNIX, and macOS.

Comment: If the file doesn't end with a newline, whatever vs code is using to display output might be waiting for one before actually displaying that last line.

Comment: @Shawn Yeah, that solved the problem. But, can you mention why VSCode is waiting for the newline, but the terminal is not?

Comment: Poorly written program?